# Error code of 7 Zip seems incorrect

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, 7zip

Running the following Batch file gives me 255 as errorlevel from 7zip, although everything seems to be ok (file correctly created, Password works):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%c IN (F:\Shares\Backup\DMS\*.*) DO (
  echo zipping %%c with errorlevel... 
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -pPassword -mx0 -t7z "%%c.7z" "%%c" > nul
  echo %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

According to 7zip error Levels, this should be 0. 255 stands for user interruption, which doesn't occur. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Try a different/newer 7zip version.

Comment: How many files are created?  try your script with just one filename to see if the errorlevel is still 255.  There is a reason why I suggest this - the result will confirm or deny my idea.

Comment: its still 255, even with one file only.